# How to resolve bindings with different scopes?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have a model (AModel) which I wanted to use as singleton. I created a custom scope named @ApplicationScope to use it for every class I need only once. So AppComponent and AModel shares this @ApplicationScope. I have some fragment (ConfirmationFragment) where I would like to use both AModel and BModel. BModel has a different scope because I'd like to use it in 3 fragments but Amodel needed everywhere.

The idea to access both AModel and BModel was to let ConfirmationComponent depend on AppComponent where AModel already available. In this way if I inject ConfirmationComponent to ConfirmationFragment I could use AModel, too.
But I got the following error:
`[Dagger/IncompatiblyScopedBindings] ConfirmationComponent scoped with @ConfirmationScope may not reference bindings with different scopes:`

Build succeeds when injecting AModel is commented out from ConfirmationFragment but fails when it isn't. I need AModel in that fragment, too.

How could I fix this problem?
(In case it's important: I use only one activity, and let Android navigation do the work with fragments.)

```kotlin
open class MyApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val appComponent = initializeComponent()
    }

    val appComponent: AppComponent by lazy {
        initializeComponent()
    }

    val confirmationComponent: ConfirmationComponent by lazy {
        initializeConfirmationComponent()
    }

    open fun initializeComponent(): AppComponent {
        return DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(applicationContext)
    }

    open fun initializeConfirmationComponent(): ConfirmationComponent {
        return DaggerConfirmationComponent.builder().appComponent(appComponent).build()
    }
}

@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = [NetworkModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance context: Context) : AppComponent
    }
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
    fun inject(fragment: ConfirmationFragment)
}

@ConfirmationScope
@Component(dependencies = [AppComponent::class])
interface ConfirmationComponent {
    fun inject(fragment: ConfirmationFragment)
}

@ApplicationScope
class AModel @Inject constructor() {}

@ConfirmationScope
class BModel @Inject constructor() {}

class ConfirmationFragment : Fragment() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var modelA : AModel

    @Inject
    lateinit var modelB : BModel

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        (requireActivity().applicationContext as MyApplication).confirmationComponent.inject(this)
    }
    // Rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put it other way around. If I got you correctly ModelA has larger scope than ModelB this means you can have ModelB as a subcomponent of ModelA with narrower scope.

So for this you would need:

1. ConfirmationComponent

```
//@YourScopeAnnotation
@Subcomponent(modules = [...]) // if it is dependent on any modules
interface ConfirmationComponent {

    // needed for dagger to create component
    @Subcomponent.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(): ConfirmationComponent
    }


    fun inject(yourFragment: Fragment) // fun inject your fragment
}
```

2. SubcomponentsModule

```
@Module(
    subcomponents = [ConfirmationComponent::class]
)
class SubcomponentsModule
```

3. In your ApplicationComponent

```
//@ApplicationScopeAnnotation  I think you can also use @Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [NetworkModule::class, SubcomponentsModule::class]
)
interface ApplicationComponent {

    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
    fun confirmationComponent(): ConfirmationComponent.Factory

}
```

4. Than just initialize ApplicationComponent in your Application class as usual
5. Now in your main activity inject ModelA which should be available globally. Also create ConfirmationComponent in your activity

```
@Inject
lateinit var modelA : AModel

lateinit var confirmationComponent: ConfirmationComponent

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    confirmationComponent = (applicationContext as MyApplication).appComponent
            .confirmationComponent()
            .create()

    modelA = (applicationContext as MyApplication).appComponent.inject(this)

}
```

6. Last step, in your fragment inject modelB and get modelA from activity

```
@Inject
    lateinit var modelB: ModelB // inject modelB

    lateinit var modelA: ModelA // get ModelA from activity where it was already injected

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        (activity as MainActivity).confirmationComponent.inject(this)

        modelA = (activity as MainActivity).modelA

    }
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I welcomed your solution first but it turns out that ``modelB`` is initialized each time I start a new fragment. So I managed to use ``modelA`` and ``modelB`` in ``ConfirmationFragment`` successfully, where ``modelB`` is initialized only when ``ConfirmationFragment`` become attached. However from ``ConfirmationFragment`` I navigate to ``ResultFragment`` (not in the example) but ``modelB`` is not the same instance as in ``ConfirmationFragment``. Am I missed something ?

Comment: I have updated answer. You can initialize `ConfirmationComponent` in your activity and use it to inject same instance of `ModelB` to your fragments

Comment: Well, I introduced a ConfirmationManager which has the @ApplicationScope and it contains the necessary data between fragments. Anyway you taught me things and this led me to my solution. Thank you!